Time complexity of Cech complex
I'm attempting to identify the time complexity of constructing the Cech complex. I'm not super confident in the answer I've given, but I'm not sure where to go next. Below, $E^{d}$ refers to an affine space with a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$, where $E = \mathbb{R^{d}}$ and $\vec{E} = \vec{R^{d}}$.
Theorem: The time complexity of constructing the Cech complex is $T(n) = \Theta(n^{k+1})$, where $k$ is the dimension of the complex and $n$ is the number of points used.
Proof: Firstly, to determine whether a k-simplex $\sigma$ belongs to the Cech complex, we must check all possible subsets of $k+1$ points from the $n$-point set $\mathcal{P}$. The number of $(k+1)$-point subsets of $\mathcal{P}$ is given by the binomial coefficient:
$$\begin{pmatrix} n  \\ k + 1 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k)}{(k+1)!}.$$
For large $n$ (where $n > k$), the dominant term in this expression behaves as:
$$\begin{pmatrix} n  \\ k + 1 \end{pmatrix} \sim \frac{n^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}.$$
$(k+1)!$ is a constant that does not grow with $n$, so asymptotically:
$$\begin{pmatrix} n  \\ k + 1 \end{pmatrix} = \Theta(n^{k+1}).$$
Secondly, for each subset of $k+1$ points $\{v_{0}, v_{1}, \cdots, v_{k}\}$, we need to determine whether the $\epsilon / 2$-balls centred at $v_{0}, v_{1}, \cdots, v_{k}$ have a non-empty intersection. This condition translates to solving the system of inequalities:
$$\exists \text{ } x \in E^{d} \text{ such that } ||x - v_{i}|| \leq \epsilon / 2 \text{ } \forall \text{ } i = 0, 1, \cdots, k.$$
The cost of solving this system depends on the dimension $d$, but does not depend on the size of the dataset $n$. Let the constant cost of solving this system be $C$.
The total computation cost $T(n)$ is the product of the number of subsets and the cost of evaluating the intersection condition for each subset:
$$T(n) = C \cdot \begin{pmatrix} n  \\ k + 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Substituting the asymptotic growth of $\begin{pmatrix} n  \\ k + 1 \end{pmatrix}$, we get:
$$T(n) = C \cdot \Theta(n^{k+1}).$$
Since $C$ is a constant, the overall growth rate is:
$$T(n) = \Theta(n^{k+1}).$$
The cost cannot exceed $\Theta(n^{k+1})$ because we are explicitely checking all subsets of $k+1$ points. The cost cannot be reduced below $\Theta(n^{k+1})$ because we must examine $\begin{pmatrix} n  \\ k + 1 \end{pmatrix}$ subsets to determine which simplices belong to the Cech complex. Thus, the bound $\Theta(n^{k+1})$ is both an upper and lower bound, making it tight.
Any corrections \ hints are appreciated! Thanks!

Don't you vary $\varepsilon$?  Wouldn't it be $O(n^2)$ pairwise distance calculations to produce a complete graph with edges marked by the distance between the vertices at its ends.  Select $\epsilon$ and only keep those edges marked ${} \leq \epsilon$, then the list of simplices is the list of cliques in this reduced graph (the number of which depends on how many edges were retained)?  Note that we can mark each clique in the full graph with the longest edge in it to keep track of the critical (minimal) $\varepsilon$ for which it appears.

You would vary $\epsilon$ when doing persistent homology; for now, I'm just looking at a single construction of the complex. It seems you use a graph-based approach whereas I use a direct combinatorial approach? If the time complexity of your method is $O(n^{2})$, isn't that the same time complexity as the Vietoris-Rips complex construction? I'm under the impression the Rips complex should be easier to compute than the Cech complex. For some context, I'm trying to compare Cech and Rips to show that Rips is actually faster than Cech, as opposed to just stating this as a given fact.

Well, $O(n^2)$ is the pairwise distance calculations.  The list of cliques in the reduced graph can be long, recovering the $O(n^k)$ estimate.  There might be a sneaky way to construct maximal contractible trees of $k$-simplices for each $k$, converting from a complex of simplices to a complex of cells.  (For homology, the resulting linear algebra is simpler.)  It sounds like you're focused on combinatorial complexes (not topological complexes) so this might not be interesting.
